# Dont show number on Call - iPhone App Development

Tags: ios, iphone, url, call

I have created a tab in my app, where the user could call the client directly from within the app.

But I wont show his number, i want to display: "Do you want to call Client?" instead of "Do you want to call 000-000-000"

I've seen this solution in another app, but dont have a clue how to do this.

Answer (score 3):

The openURL call does not automatically prompt the user for anything.

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"tel:7205551212"]];
```

It's good practice to confirm with the user, but it's up to you to determine the message. To show the alert, do something like this:

```
UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Confirmation" message:@"Do you want to call Client?" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"No" otherButtonTitles:@"Yes", nil];
[alertView show];
[alertView release];
```

Then make the actual phone call in a UIAlertViewDelegate method:

```
- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex {
    if (buttonIndex == 1) {
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"tel:7205551212"]];
    }
}
```